# Does Dojo Framework have the version set in it somewhere?

Tags: dojo, version

I have a copy of Dojo framework but i am not sure which version it is.
How can you tell? Surely it must be set as a value in it somewhere.
 My downloaded folder looks like this:

```
dojo\
 dijit\
 dojo\
 dojox\
 util\
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following on from JW's answer above, it look like in Dojo 1.8 and 1.9 the dojo.version property is set in

```
dojo/_base/kernel.js
```

Look for the line starting with:

```
dojo.version =
```

Answer (score 4):

aaah got it: its set in:

```
dojo\
 dojo\
  _base\
   _loader\
    bootstrap.js
```

Answer (score 3):

`dojo.version` will give you the details of the exact version you're using.

Here is an example of the output:

```
>>> dojo.version;
0.0.0dev (15278) major=0 minor=0 patch=0 flag=dev revision=15278
>>> dojo.version.toString();
"0.0.0dev (15278)"
```